# Why is the exception thrown on memcpy using during copying LPBYTE to LPTSTR (clipboard)?

Tags: c++, memcpy, lptstr

I have a LPBYTE array (taken from file) and I need to copy it into LPTSRT (actually into the clipboard). The trouble is copying work but unstable, sometime an exception was thrown (not always) and I don't understand why. The code is:

```
     FILE *fConnect = _wfopen(connectFilePath, _T("rb"));
  if (!fConnect)
   return;
  fseek(fConnect, 0, SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell(fConnect);
  rewind(fConnect);

  LPBYTE lpByte = (LPBYTE) malloc(lSize);  
  fread(lpByte, 1, lSize, fConnect); 
  lpByte[lSize] = 0;
  fclose(fConnect);

  //Copy into clipboard
  BOOL openRes = OpenClipboard(NULL);
  if (!openRes)
   return;
  DWORD err = GetLastError();

  EmptyClipboard(); 
  HGLOBAL hText;
  hText = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, (lSize+ sizeof(TCHAR)));

  LPTSTR sMem = (TCHAR*)GlobalLock(hText); 
  memcpy(sMem, lpByte, (lSize + sizeof(TCHAR)));
```

The last string is the place where the exception is thrown.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I'm not saying, it's the cause of Your problems, but it may be or may be a cause of other problems in the future.

If You allocate memory like this

```
LPBYTE lpByte = (LPBYTE) malloc(lSize);
```

This is an access outside of the allocated chunk of memory:

```
lpByte[lSize] = 0;
```

Allocated memory has size of `lSize` and it contains locations form `&lpByte[0]` to `&lpByte[lSize - 1]` inclusive.

**EDIT:**

As Hans noticed, `memcpy` also accesses the memory outside of the allocated block. If `sizeof(TCHAR)` is 1, the last read byte is `lpByte[lSize]` and if `sizeof(TCHAR)` is more that 1, bytes past `lpByte[lSize]` are also read or at least attempted to be.

Comment: It is outside of the bounds, and you've caught a serious problem

Comment: It seems to me I know the what the exception is, the code is 800401fd Object is not connected to server
But I don't have any idea what it means

Comment: The memcpy() is out of bound too, possibly by 2.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what causes problems in your code, but the following code works and everything is *locked / copied* fine *(note that your clipboard operations could be easily commented out and have no impact on the problem's source)*:

```
   LPBYTE lpByte = (LPBYTE)malloc(512);  
   lpByte[0] = 'A';
   lpByte[1] = 'B';
   lpByte[2] = '0';

   // OpenClipboard(NULL);
   // EmptyClipboard(); 

   HGLOBAL hText;
   hText = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, 512);

   LPTSTR sMem = (TCHAR*)GlobalLock(hText); 
   memcpy(sMem, lpByte, 512);
```

*You could try setting breakpoints in your code right before the exception **happens** (it could actually have different reasons).*

Comment: Suer I could but I don't know what to look at... the most nasty is the exception is thrown not always, and I don't know what the exception is it.

Answer (score 0):

Do GlobalAlloc or GlobalLock work? Put some error checking code in and see, both should return non-NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

`_wfopen` is the wide character version of `fopen` - you should be passing it L"...", not TCHARs. The TCHAR version is `_tfopen` (which will boil down to one of `fopen` or `_wfopen`) - See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28VS.80%29.aspx

```
LPBYTE lpByte = (LPBYTE) malloc(lSize);
```

If this is C, you don't really need to cast malloc's result. Personally, the MS `LP*` types leave a bad taste in my mouth - I feel the Hungarian obscures the readability of the code to someone well versed in... C. Thus, I prefer `BYTE *` over `LPBYTE`, but it's not going to make or break code.

```
fread(lpByte, 1, lSize, fConnect);
```

Check the return value.

```
lpByte[lSize] = 0;
```

As others mentioned, this memory access is out of the array bounds.

```
if (!openRes)
    return;
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

- You leak `lpByte`
- You call `GetLastError()` ... on success?

Next,

```
LPTSTR sMem = (TCHAR*)GlobalLock(hText);
```

While I prefer the non-LP stuff, perhaps choose one? (Maybe make the cast `LPTSTR`?) Again, it shouldn't matter in the end. (This might fall under a "It's a malloc, and doesn't need a cast" as well.)

```
memcpy(sMem, lpByte, (lSize + sizeof(TCHAR)));
```

As others mentioned, this memcpy is also accessing invalid memory. Specifically, `lpByte` is `lSize` long, but you're doing that plus an extra `sizeof(TCHAR)`.